# If $\Omega$ is locally Lipschitz, then $\Omega = \bigcup_{k = 1}^N \Omega_k$ for $\Omega_k$ star shaped with respect to an open ball $B_k$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology

I am reading Galdi's *Introduction to the mathematical theory of Navier Stokes equations* and there is an argument which comes up quite often that I really don't understand.

In many theorems of Chapter $3$, we prove the existence of solutions of a problem defined on an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ that statisfies the following condition:
$$\Omega = \bigcup_{k  = 1}^N \Omega_k$$
where each $\Omega_k$ is star shaped with respect to some open ball $B_k$ with $\overline{B}_k \subset \Omega_k$.

Then, in the next chapters, he uses these results but for $\Omega$ bounded and locally Lipschitz. Therefore, it seems to me that a bounded locally Lipschitz open set should satisfy the above condition, but I really have no idea how to show that.. Clearly $\overline{\Omega}$ is compact, so we can cover it by a finite number of balls, but then how do we prove that they are star-shaped with respect to some other balls $B_k$ ? Any idea ?

Comment: It seems that you have to prove this property only for the (sub-) graph of a Lipschitz function on a ball. This smells like rather elementary geometry -- but I do not claim to see it immediately.

Comment: Yes,consider now a Cauchy sequence in W^(1,p) ìntersecting' the ball

Answer (score 3):

This is a well known result, see for example Lemma 1 on page 15 in [M]. We say that a domain satisfies a *cone condition* if every point in the domain is a vertex of a fixed cone that is entirely contained in the domain. Clearly Lipschitz domains have the cone condition. Then Lemma 1 on page 15 is:

> **Theorem.** Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain having the cone property. Then $\Omega$ is the union of a finite number of domains with respect to a ball.

The proof given in [M] is short, elementary and well written.

**[M] V. Maz'ya,** *Sobolev spaces with applications to elliptic partial differential equations.* Second, revised and augmented edition. Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften 342. Springer, Heidelberg, 2011.

Answer (score -3):

Because $\bar{\Omega}$ is compact, it can be considered in the interior of a fixed star domain, say with respect to the origin. One then must use the well known Nikodym property of $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of differentiability on almost all lines parallel to the coordinate axes.

Comment: I am not following where the Nikodym property is applied. Could you give some more detail please?

Comment: Prof. McKay, in respect of the given compact boundary, consider a finite number of hyperplane sections. Now consider any Cauchy sequence in $W^{1,p} (\mathbb{R}^n)$ intersecting the boundary. This is what I had in mind.

Comment: @BenMcKay This answer makes no sense so no reason to ask abouy Nikodym's property. It is completely irrelevant.